# Is it safe to remove the .oh-my-zsh directory?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

One point in time, I tried oh my zsh but it causes a lot of issues so I'm back at bash. I'm trying to clean up some files and notice there is a oh my zsh folder. The github instructions tell me to run uninstall oh my zsh but I don't see that script in my folder.

Is it safe to remove `.oh-my-zsh` folder?

Comment: Have you already run `chsh`? What are you concerned with if you're switching back to `bash`? Perhaps create a tar backup with `tar cfp oh-my-zsh.tar oh-my-zsh/` and then remove it (if you want to be able to restore it later).

Comment: Read this StackOverflow Q&A - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813983/troubles-uninstalling-oh-my-zsh  It includes a link to the script on github.

Comment: Pay attention to what you're reading. Punctuation matters. It's not “uninstall oh my zsh” but `uninstall_oh_my_sh`, not “oh my zsh folder” but `.oh-my-zsh` (and it's called a directory unless you're using Windows).

Comment: As a side note, did you consider trying zsh without oh-my-zsh? Deciding not to use zsh because of it is like deciding not to use bash because you don't like someone else's `.bashrc` they gave you.

Comment: @Patrick. Yes. I like the flashiness of zsh with oh-my-zsh but I ran into issues especially with RVM. It's already pretty hard for me to understand bundle with RVM and I always get confused. Gave me a day's worth of headache. Maybe in the future, I'll try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.oh-my-zsh` isn't used by anything but oh-my-zsh. If you use bash, you can just remove it.

The [instructions](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) tell you to run the command `uninstall_oh_my_zsh`. This is a function that you can invoke from zsh running oh-my-zsh. If you aren't running oh-my-zsh, you can run `tools/uninstall.sh`, but all it does is:

- remove `~/.oh-my-zsh`, which you were going to do anyway;
- switch your login shell to bash, which you've already done;
- restore your old `~/.zshrc`, which you didn't have if you never used zsh without oh-my-zsh.

You could also use zsh without oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally save, because it could cause leftover configuration from oh-my-zsh.

The setup of oh-my-zsh adds some lines to your zsh startup files, like ~/.zshrc
The uninstall program you already looked for would remove these added lines.

The problem caused by the leftover configutation could make zsh show error messages at start, or stop running the shell startup scripts somewhere inbetween.
All that can be confusing to fix without knowing the scripts.

So, for now, I propose to keep the directory until you found and used the uninstall script.

If you end up running in errors at zsh start related to this, please show the error messages.

(Please clarify which folder to remove you talk about exactly)